# Flexbox column wrap not working in latest Safari if children have min-width

Tags: html, css, macos, safari, flexbox

After upgrading safari (to 10.1.1) and mac os (to sierra), column wrap no longer works with a list of items that have a min-width set. I've tried setting various flex properties on the children, but safari doesn't seem to be able to wrap them in columns once this is set. It is working in the other browsers I need to support and was working in the 10.0.1 version of safari. I've made a codepen that simulates the code as it currently is on the site - 
http://codepen.io/ssanders/pen/KmJgwK

Important -
You need to have these -

*Safari- Version 10.1.1

*mac os - sierra

```
.list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 600px;
}

.item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  min-width: 340px;
}
```

Comment: What happens in Safari 10.1.1? I get that it doesn't wrap, but can you provide a description or an illustration of the actual rendering?

Comment: Since it isn't wrapping, the items continue in a single line, going out of the content area and past the boundaries of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting a bug and reaching out to the safari support team, it appears this was a bug specific to version 10.1.1 of safari. It has been fixed in subsequent releases.